# Failing to Push docker image from Jenkins on GCE instance to google container registry

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I am trying to push docker image from jenkins configured on compute engine with default service account. But it is failing with this error:

> [Docker] ERROR: failed to push image gcr.io/project-id/sms-impl:work ERROR: Build step failed with exception com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Could not push image: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate to Container Registry, use gcloud as a Docker credential helper. To do so, run the following command:

gcloud auth configure-docker

You need to run this command once to authenticate to Container Registry. We strongly recommend that you use this method when possible. It provides secure, short-lived access to your project resources. Please follow steps as link [1](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the page that was linked, you will see a further link to [Using GCR with GCP](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-with-google-cloud-platform), in particular, [this section](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-with-google-cloud-platform#compute-engine) describes what you need to do.

To summarize, the service account needs the permissions to *write* to the storage bucket for GCR.  Since you mentioned you were using the default service account, it further will need the [access scopes](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-with-google-cloud-platform#access_scopes) set for that instance.  The default only grants 'read' unless you have specified all scopes.

A few ways to do this:

- When you create the instance using gcloud, specify `--scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`
- In the console, select the scope specifically or select "all scopes", e.g.:

[image: options for scopes on instance create page]

(... many lines of scopes omitted ...)

[image: correct setting for storage scope]

You can also add the scopes after the fact, if needed, by editing the instance while it is stopped.

Note that the *first* push for a project may additionally require "admin" rights, in order to create the bucket.

Comment: followed the steps mentioned above. Still facing same issue.